# Using XmlSlurper: How to select sub-elements while iterating over a GPathResult

Tags: html, parsing, groovy, xmlslurper

I am writing an HTML parser, which uses TagSoup to pass a well-formed structure to XMLSlurper.

Here's the generalised code:

```
def htmlText = """
<html>
<body>
<div id="divId" class="divclass">
<h2>Heading 2</h2>
<ol>
<li><h3><a class="box" href="#href1">href1 link text</a> <span>extra stuff</span></h3><address>Here is the address<span>Telephone number: <strong>telephone</strong></span></address></li>
<li><h3><a class="box" href="#href2">href2 link text</a> <span>extra stuff</span></h3><address>Here is another address<span>Another telephone: <strong>0845 1111111</strong></span></address></li>
</ol>
</div>
</body>
</html>
"""     

def html = new XmlSlurper(new org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup.Parser()).parseText( htmlText );

html.'**'.grep { it.@class == 'divclass' }.ol.li.each { linkItem ->
    def link = linkItem.h3.a.@href
    def address = linkItem.address.text()
    println "$link: $address\n"
}
```

I would expect the each to let me select each 'li' in turn so I can retrieve the corresponding href and address details. Instead, I am getting this output:

```
#href1#href2: Here is the addressTelephone number: telephoneHere is another addressAnother telephone: 0845 1111111
```

I've checked various example on the web and these either deal with XML, or are one-liner examples like "retrieve all links from this file". It's seems that the it.h3.a.@href expression is collecting all hrefs in the text, even though I'm passing it a reference to the parent 'li' node.

Can you let me know:

- Why I'm getting the output shown
- How I can retrieve the href/address pairs for each 'li' item

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Replace grep with find:

```
html.'**'.find { it.@class == 'divclass' }.ol.li.each { linkItem ->
    def link = linkItem.h3.a.@href
    def address = linkItem.address.text()
    println "$link: $address\n"
}
```

then you'll get

```
#href1: Here is the addressTelephone number: telephone

#href2: Here is another addressAnother telephone: 0845 1111111
```

grep returns an ArrayList but find returns a NodeChild class:

```
println html.'**'.grep { it.@class == 'divclass' }.getClass()
println html.'**'.find { it.@class == 'divclass' }.getClass()
```

results in:

```
class java.util.ArrayList
class groovy.util.slurpersupport.NodeChild
```

thus if you wanted to use grep you could then nest another each like this for it to work

```
html.'**'.grep { it.@class == 'divclass' }.ol.li.each {
    it.each { linkItem ->
        def link = linkItem.h3.a.@href
        def address = linkItem.address.text()
        println "$link: $address\n"
    }
}
```

Long story short, in your case, use find rather than grep.

Answer (score 1):

This was is a tricky one. When there is just one element with class='divclass' the previous answer sure is fine. If there were multiple results from grep, then a find() for a single result is not the answer. Pointing out that the result is an ArrayList is correct. Inserting an outer nested .each() loop provides a GPathResult in the closure parameter *div*. From here the drill down can continue with the expected result.

```
html."**".grep { it.@class == 'divclass' }.each { div -> div.ol.li.each { linkItem ->
   def link = linkItem.h3.a.@href
   def address = linkItem.address.text()
   println "$link: $address\n"
}}
```

The behavior of the original code can use a bit more of an explanation as well. When a property is accessed on a List in Groovy, you'll get a new list (same size) with the property of each element in the list. The list found by grep() has just one entry. Then we get one entry for property *ol*, which is fine. Next we get the result of ol.it for that entry. It is a list of size() == 1 again, but this time with an entry of size() == 2. We could apply the outer loop there and get the same result, if we wanted to:

```
html."**".grep { it.@class == 'divclass' }.ol.li.each { it.each { linkItem ->
   def link = linkItem.h3.a.@href
   def address = linkItem.address
   println "$link: $address\n"
}}
```

On any GPathResult representing multiple nodes, we get the concatenation of all text. That is the original result, first for *@href*, then for *address*.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the previous answers are all correct at the time of writing, for the version used. But I am using HTTPBuilder 0.7.1 and Grails 2.4.4 with Groovy 2.3.7 and there is a big issue - **HTML elements are transformed to uppercase.** It appears this is due to NekoHTML used under the hood:

http://nekohtml.sourceforge.net/faq.html#uppercase

Because of this, the solution in the accepted answer must be written as:

```
html.'**'.find { it.@class == 'divclass' }.OL.LI.each { linkItem ->
    def link = linkItem.H3.A.@href
    def address = linkItem.ADDRESS.text()
    println "$link: $address\n"
}
```

This was very frustrating to debug, hope it helps someone.